# C++ line repeats 8 times outside of a loop

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I am writing a connect 4 program to reinforce my understanding of pointers, and decided to write it all in a class (I began learning programming in Java), but a certain line of code repeats over and over when it is reached and I cannot understand why.

I am using XCode. Here is the code I am running:

```
class Connect_4{

public:

char **p_p_board = NULL;
int w; //Width stores the arrays that make up the vertical columns of the connect 4 board
int h; //Height is how large the arrays that make up the vertical colums are
Player *p_player_1 = NULL;
Player *p_player_2 = NULL;
bool player_two_turn = false;

Connect_4(){

    w = 7;
    h = 6;

    p_player_1 = new Player('x');
    p_player_2 = new Player('+');

    init_board();

}

Connect_4(int width, int height){

    w = width;
    h = height;

    p_player_1 = new Player('x');
    p_player_2 = new Player('+');

    init_board();

}

Connect_4(int width, int height, Player* one, Player* two){

    w = width;
    h = height;

    p_player_1 = one;
    p_player_2 = two;

    init_board();

}

void init_board(){

    p_p_board = new char*[w];

    for(int i = 0; i < w; i++){

        p_p_board[i] = new char[h];

        for(int j = 0; j < h; j++){

            p_p_board[i][j] = '_';

        }

    }

}

void draw(){

    cout<<"\n";

    for(int i = h; i >= 0; i--){
        for(int j = 0; j < w; j++){

            if(i != h){

                cout<<p_p_board[j][i]<<" ";

            }else{

                cout<<j<<" ";

            }

        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    cout<<"\n";

}

bool insert_piece(int index, char piece){

    bool inserted = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < h; i++){

        if(p_p_board[index][i] == '_'){

            p_p_board[index][i] = piece;
            inserted = true;
            break;

        }

    }

    return inserted;

}

void check_board(){

    char p1 = p_player_1->p;
    char **p = p_p_board;

    for(int i = 0; i < w; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < h-3; j++){

            if(p[i][j] == '_') break;

            if(p[i][j] == p[i][j+1] && p[i][j] == p[i][j+2] && p[i][j] == p[i][j+3]){
                if(p[i][j] == p1){
                    p_player_1->won = true;
                    break;
                }else{
                    p_player_2->won = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

}

void turn(){

    draw();

    int input;

    cout<<"Player "<<(player_two_turn+1)<<", it is your turn. In which column will you drop a piece?  ";
    cin>>input;

    if(input >= w || input < 0){
        cout<<"ERROR: INVALID INPUT";
        cout<<"\n";
        sleep(1);
        turn();
    }

    if(!player_two_turn){
        if(!insert_piece(input, p_player_1->p)){
            cout<<"ERROR: COULD NOT INSERT PIECE";
            cout<<"\n";
            sleep(1);
            turn();
        }
    }else{
        if(!insert_piece(input, p_player_2->p)){
            cout<<"ERROR: COULD NOT INSERT PIECE";
            cout<<"\n";
            sleep(1);
            turn();
        }
    }

    check_board();

    if(!p_player_1->won && !p_player_2->won){
        player_two_turn = !player_two_turn;
        turn();
    }

    if(p_player_1->won){
        cout<<"Player one is the winner!\n";
    }else{
        cout<<"Player two is the winner!\n";
    }

}

};

int main()
{

    Connect_4 game = Connect_4();

    game.turn();

    cin.get();


}
```

This is the offending code:

```
    if(p_player_1->won){
        cout<<"Player one is the winner!\n";
    }else{
        cout<<"Player two is the winner!\n";
    }
```

Whenever a player wins, the line "Player x is the winner!" is repeated 8 times in the console like so:

```
Player one is the winner!
Player one is the winner!
Player one is the winner!
Player one is the winner!
Player one is the winner!
Player one is the winner!
Player one is the winner!
Player one is the winner!
```

Can anyone help me shed light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Every call to `Connect_4::turn()` will result in a "winner!" message.  Do you see that?

Comment: Show us the constructor. In C++ member variables aren't instantiated to anything by default so the first guess is that you haven't initialised `won` to `false`. This contrasts with the Objective-C pattern, whereby all instance variables are initialised to binary 0s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your turn() method is clearly recursive, so once the game completes, it will print out "Player X has won!" For the number of turns your game ran.

The best way to fix the problem would be to refactor the code so it's using a loop that is broken by a win condition, rather than going recursive.

Comment: I can't accept your answer just yet, but it sounds as if it's correct! I feel dumb for not seeing it yet and how stupid it was of me to make it recursive, since for some reason I thought that the original function would go on to finish running itself as opposed to waiting for the recursive calls to the function to finish before continuing. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I would suggest you to decide the winner outside this TURN method. :)